# Session is not Defined Using OpenShift for a Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, openshift, session-variables

I am trying to use OpenShift for my Meteor application which uses session variables. The application loads fully, but once the user begins interacting with it, the site fails to load anything because "ReferenceError: Session is not defined." This is really weird because the application runs flawlessly on localhost. Anyone know why this could occur?

Comment: Have you added the 'Session' package with 'meteor add session' ?  I've had the same error in the past when I forgot to add the package.

Comment: I forgot to come back to this question! I actually managed to figure it out and Joos was right. For whatever reason, sessions were working on localhost without the session package, but wouldn't work on OpenShift. I'm new to StackOverflow, but if I could, I'd mark your answer as approved/correct. Maybe if some mod could do it for future users.

Comment: Perhaps because it's a comment? I've basically said the same thing, but this time as an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks! I marked it as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the 'Session' package with 'meteor add session'. I've had the same error in the past when I forgot to add the package.